# Material-UI React form validation

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI and I need some library which will provide me validation on forms. I want it to work on the principle that I provide a schema for forms in which I define validation and on submit it will return me the names of the inputs where there are errors with message error. Can you recommend any library?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend on [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) or [formik](https://formik.org/docs/examples/with-material-ui). Both can be used with schema validation like `Yup`, `Zod` or `Joi`. Personally I've worked with `Yup` with react-form-hook and MUI and it was a good experience.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) for defining my schemas, coupled with [react-hook-form](https://github.com/react-hook-form/resolvers#zod).

There's a [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sto0v) which gives a great example that should help get you started (I take no credit for it, but it really helped me get started).